# How to find missing pairs in many-to-many table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given: Users and Groups, as well as many-to-many GroupUsers table.

It is necessary that each pair of users has its own paired group, provided that there can be groups with more or less users.

How to check and create the missing paired groups?

[Link to SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3c30f)

```sql
create table dbo.Users (
    Id   int not null,
    Name nvarchar(50) not null,
    constraint PK_Users primary key clustered (Id)
);
create table dbo.Groups (
    Id   int not null,
    Name nvarchar(50) not null, 
    constraint PK_Groups primary key clustered (Id)
);
create table dbo.GroupUsers (
    GroupId int not null ,
    UserId  int not null ,
    constraint PK_GroupUsers primary key clustered (GroupId, UserId),
    constraint FK_GroupUsers_GroupId foreign key (GroupId) references dbo.Groups (Id),
    constraint FK_GroupUsers_UserId foreign key (UserId) references dbo.Users (Id)
);

insert into dbo.Users values (1, 'Anna'), (2, 'Berta'), (3, 'Carlie'), (4, 'Dana'), (5, 'Emil');
insert into dbo.Groups values (1, 'Anna-Berta'), (2, 'Anna-Carlie'), (3, 'Anna-Berta-Carlie');
insert into dbo.GroupUsers values 
(1,1), (1, 2), -- 'Anna-Berta' group
(2,1), (2, 3), -- 'Anna-Carlie' group
(3,1), (3, 2), (3, 3); -- 'Anna-Berta-Carlie' group
```

How to find and create missing "Pair Group" for user Anna?

- So Anna has a Pair Group with all other users
- and all the Anna's Pair Groups must have exactly two users,
- although any user including Anna may have a group which includes more or less than two users.

**UPDATE 2019-12-15**:

So here ([Link to SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3c30f/69)) is my favorite solution (so far) of how to find missing paired groups and their users (Thanks to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59324259/623190) from [@Kari F.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4552354/kari-f))

```sql
declare @UserId int = 1;

with cte as 
(
    select
        VirtualGroupId = row_number() over(order by p.Id desc) * -1,
        GroupName = concat( u.Name, '_', p.Name),
        CurrentUserId = u.Id, 
        OtherUserId = p.Id
    from 
        dbo.Users u inner join dbo.Users p on u.Id = @UserId and p.Id <> @UserId
    where       
        concat('_', u.Id, '_', p.Id) not in 
        (
            select
                (
                    select concat('_', gu.UserId) 
                    from dbo.GroupUsers gu 
                    where gu.GroupId = g.Id
                    order by case when gu.UserId = @UserId then 0 else 1 end
                    for xml path ('')
                )
            from                         
                dbo.Groups g
         )
)
select VirtualGroupId, GroupName, UserId = CurrentUserId from cte
union all
select VirtualGroupId, GroupName, UserId = OtherUserId from cte 
order by VirtualGroupId, UserId
```

Comment: This is a well-written question and you have not shown us your attempt to solve the problem. Hint: you need a WHERE clause that detects null values

Comment: In this scenario what is the expected output? Are you looking for 2 groups to be identified called "Anna-Dana" and "Anna-Emil" and then to have those groups created automatically?

Comment: Output is the creation of the missing paired groups.

Comment: Output is the finding of the missing "Anna-Dana" and "Anna-Emil" groups first.
The creation is simple, but would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this simple solution:

```
 select u.Id, p.Id
  from dbo.Users u 
  cross join dbo.Users p
  where u.Id = 1 and p.Id <> 1
    and u.Name + '-' + p.Name not in (select g.Name from dbo.Groups g);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3c30f/16

**Second solution taking into account you comment**

```
with required_groups as (
   select u.Id as userId, p.Id pairId
    from dbo.Users u 
    cross join dbo.Users p
    where u.Id = 1 and p.Id <> 1
 ),
 existing_groups as (
   select annas_groups.UserId as userId, pairs_groups.UserId as pairId
     from (
       select *
         from GroupUsers gu
         where gu.UserId = 1
           and gu.GroupId in (
             select x.GroupId from GroupUsers x
               group by x.GroupId
               having count(*) = 2
         )
      ) annas_groups
      inner join (
       select *
         from GroupUsers gu
         where 
           gu.UserId <> 1
           and gu.GroupId in (
             select x.GroupId from GroupUsers x
               group by x.GroupId
               having count(*) = 2
         )        
      ) pairs_groups on annas_groups.GroupId = pairs_groups.GroupId
 )

 select * 
   from required_groups rg
   where not exists (
       select 1 
         from existing_groups eg 
         where eg.UserId = rg.UserId 
           and eg.PairId = rg.PairId
   )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3c30f/34

A bit more complex but still readable, I think.

Comment: Ha-ha, nice try! :) Formally you are right, but the names of groups are there for better understanding and can be of any name.

Comment: I really like it :) Thank you!

Comment: Well I was just following the KISS principle as far as possible ;). Now I added another solution but posted wrong code block. Sorry for editing my post several times.

Comment: Kari, thank you for your second solution. I would agree it is strightforward and a little bit complex.

Comment: Kari, I would prefer making the second step from your first suggestion: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3c30f/50

Comment: and then the whole query to find missing groups and uts users is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3c30f/67

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to solve the problem using a loop approach, this is because the id from the groups table must be supplied and is not an identity column otherwise the implementation becomes simpler.

I've also used a keyuser variable to handle the fact that it is "Anna" who must be paired and not some other user. This avoids simply hard coding the userid value.

```
create table #Users (
    Id   int not null,
    Name nvarchar(50) not null,
    constraint PK_Users primary key clustered (Id)
);
create table #Groups (
    Id   int not null,
    Name nvarchar(50) not null, 
    constraint PK_Groups primary key clustered (Id)
);
create table #GroupUsers (
    GroupId int not null ,
    UserId  int not null ,
    constraint PK_GroupUsers primary key clustered (GroupId, UserId),
    constraint FK_GroupUsers_GroupId foreign key (GroupId) references #Groups (Id),
    constraint FK_GroupUsers_UserId foreign key (UserId) references #Users (Id)
);

insert into #Users values (1, 'Anna'), (2, 'Berta'), (3, 'Carlie'), (4, 'Dana'), (5, 'Emil');
insert into #Groups values (1, 'Anna-Berta'), (2, 'Anna-Carlie'), (3, 'Anna-Berta-Carlie');
insert into #GroupUsers values 
(1,1), (1, 2), -- 'Anna-Berta' group
(2,1), (2, 3), -- 'Anna-Carlie' group
(3,1), (3, 2), (3, 3); -- 'Anna-Berta-Carlie' group

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '';
declare @nextgroupid int = 0;
declare @keyuser int = 0;

select @keyuser = ID from #Users where [Name]='Anna';

while exists (select 1 from #Users u inner join #Users u2 on u.Id=1 where u2.Id not in (select userid from #GroupUsers))
begin

select @nextgroupid = MAX(id)+1 from #Groups;

set @sql = 'insert #groups (id, [name]) select top 1 ' + CAST(@nextgroupid as nvarchar(3)) + ', u.[name] + ''-'' + u2.[name] as missingusergroup from #Users u inner join #Users u2 on u.Id= ' + CAST(@keyuser as nvarchar(3)) + ' where u2.Id not in (select userid from #GroupUsers) order by u2.id;';
exec(@sql);
set @sql = 'insert #groupusers (groupid, userid) select top 1 ' + CAST(@nextgroupid as nvarchar(3)) + ', u2.id from #Users u inner join #Users u2 on u.Id= ' + CAST(@keyuser as nvarchar(3)) + ' where u2.Id not in (select userid from #GroupUsers) union select top 1 '+ CAST(@nextgroupid as nvarchar(3)) +', u.id from #Users u where u.id= ' + CAST(@keyuser as nvarchar(3)) + ' order by u2.id;';
exec(@sql);
end

select * from #GroupUsers;

select * from #Groups;

drop table #Groups, #GroupUsers, #Users;
```

[image]

Comment: Dwight, thank you for the example, however I hope this task can be solved without explicit iteration — just by query. At least I am looking for that kind of elegant solution.